# How to force file saving with ISO-8859-1 encoding instead of UTF-8

Tags: php, xml, symfony, encoding, utf-8

I have to able `xml` files downloading with `ISO-8859-1` (I know, that `UTF-8` is much better, but our partner has strict requirements to encoding and we cannot force him to change his policy).

**Server background**:

- Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Ubuntu 16.04
- nginx
- php 7.2
- Symfony 4.0.15

Controller returns a response with proper charset:

```php
return (new Response($xml->content(), Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['Content-Type' => $xml->contentType()]))
    ->setCharset($xml->charset());
```

It looks perfectly fine (at least in Chrome DevTools there is a correct response header):

[image]

But problem is that file stored in the file system with `UTF-8` encoding.

```sh
$ file --mime test.xml 
test.xml: application/xml; charset=utf-8
```

and XML file renders incorrect after opening it in the browser:

```xml
<INSIGMA>
    <AktuarMed>
       <Person>
           <Name>Hans MÃ¼ller</Name>
           <Surname>MÃ¼ller</Surname>
           <Forename>Hans</Forename>
       </Person>
    </AktuarMed>
</INSIGMA>
```

Surname has to be *Müller*, but it is displaying wrong. If I change the encoding of this file to the expected one, then it displays it correct:

```sh
$ iconv -f UTF-8 test.xml -t ISO-8859-1 > test.xml
$ file --mime test.xml 
test.xml: application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1
```

**TL;DR: So the question is**

Why this file stores with `utf-8` encoding at all, if the server responds, that `ISO-8859-1` charset should be used?

- Do I need to send some extra headers to force downloading file with `ISO-8859-1` charset? or
- Does it default behaviour of the browser? or
- Does it default behaviour of the operating system?

How to catch this problem and on which step should I find a solution?

Comment: what is `$xml` (as seen in `$xml->content()`) and where does it come from?

Comment: @Joni `$xml` it is a custom Entity., that has `->content()` method (it returns `xml` content as a string) and `->charset()` method (it returns `ISO-8859-1` string). And as a result server returns a valid XML file, but with `utf-8` encoding

Comment: It looks like it's lying to you: `content()` returns UTF-8 encoded text while `charset()` tells you it's iso-8859-1. You can convert the encoding on the spot with iconv (`iconv("utf-8", "iso8859-1", $xml->content())`) but maybe you prefer to fix the problem at the source

Comment: @Joni, thanks that sounds like a good idea. But right now it throws an Exception `Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`

Comment: @Joni, unfortunately, that did not help. `$xml->content()` has `ISO-8859-1` encoding, but file still saves with `utf-8`

Comment: Then it sounds like the data really isn't UTF-8 originally but gets converted during the download by php, nginx, or chrome. To find where: Test with another browser and with curl. Test downloading an xml file (not generated by PHP). Test a simpler PHP script that only uses header and print functions, no framework.

Comment: It's also possible that you have mixed content within the string, some in UTF-8 and some in iso8859-1. Is the xml in your question the whole file or is there more?

Comment: It's strange that$ file --mime test.xml 
test.xml: application/xml; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: Divide and conquer. What is your server actually sending? On the client use Fiddler,  Wireshark or similar to inspect the headers and the body bytes.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yes, I am using `SimpleXMLElement` and then call `$xml->asXML()` to get it as a string. But I tried to convert that string using `iconv` and `mb_convert_encoding`, and nevertheless, it saves with `utf-8`

Comment: I've removed my answer where I explained how SimpleXML handles text encoding and how to use it to generate ISO-8859-1 since you were so disappointed by it. I'm sorry but I have no clue of what you're asking but, hopefully, someone else will.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Create xml file that should act as your server response in gedit, in 'Save as' select proper character encoding (ISO-8859-1) at the bottom of the dialog.
2. Put the file into nginx and make at accessible (public) by some URL (like http://localhost/sample-response.xml or something else).
3. Access it with your browser
4. Ensure that it's correct on the client side (after saving with browser)
5. Record xml file downloading (accessing) request-response log (with wireshark or tcpflow or something else) as plain text.
6. Now access php application for the xml file generated by your php app  and record its request-response log as in step #5
7. Compare request-response logs from step 5 & 6 with file comparison tool (meld, kdiff3 or something else)

After that you might see where the problem is.